# Python Import Error: No module named 'PyQt4'

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I'm trying to run a Python program that tries to import

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
```

and gives me an `Import Error: No module named 'PyQt4'`.

I use a conda environment and made sure: `pyqt` is installed, version 5.6.0.

If I change the import statement to

```
from pyqt import QtGui, QtCore
```

It doesn't work either, it gives me the same import error. At this point I'm totally confused:

1. Why is it telling me there is no module named `pyqt`? I know it is there. If I type `conda list` it shows me that it is installed.
2. Trying to install `PyQt4` via `pip` or `conda` fails because apparently there is not package named `PyQt4`, there is only a package named `pyqt`. How can this program try to import `PyQt4` then?
3. How can I fix this?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 3.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4`

Comment: Thanks @a_manthey_67, but it was already installed: `python3-pyqt4 is already the newest version (4.11.4+dfsg-1build4).` :/ Any other suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Try using PyQt5 like below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
```